# Find conditions where implicit function exists

Tags: functions, derivatives, optimization

Consider the following optimisation problem:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x,w,z \,\in \, R^+_0}{\text{maximize}}
& & F(x,w,z) - xc_x - wc_w - zc_z
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

where $c_i$ are positive constants.

Consider variable $z$. The first order condition for it gives $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z} = c_z$. This FOC is an equation with three variables, namely $x, w$ and $z$.

The question is: under which conditions of function $F(\cdot)$ is it possible to rearrange this FOC in order to find a closed-form expression for the conditional function of $z$ in terms of $x$ and $w$, $\hat z(x,w)$?

I can give many examples where such is the case and of others where it is not:

1. For any homogeneous function of the type $F(x,w,z) = x^{a_x} w^{a_w} z^{a_z}$, where $a_i$ as positive constants, it is possible to find such expression.
2. For any homogeneous function of the type $F(x,w,z) = (x^{a}+ w^{a}+ z^{a})^{\frac{b}{a}}$ it is not.
3. An example of a non-homogeneous function where it is possible is $F(x,w,z) = x^{a_x}w^{a_w} + z^{a_z}$.
4. An example of a non-homogeneous function where it is not possible is $F(x,w,z) = x^{a_x} + w^{a_w}z^{a_z}$.

Clearly homogeneity is neither sufficient not necessary. The only pattern I can see from above is that functional separability between $z$ and the other variables might be a **necessary and sufficient** condition (although not sure with case 2, which seems also to be functionally separable). I cannot think of a counterexample of a functionally separable function where the request is not possible (except for a linear function where $z$ disappears altogether, totally uninteresting and not really a solution).

Any hints?

PD: bounty coming to reward any help.